# How to best query AWS table without missing data using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following code that iterates through the rows of certain tables in AWS. It grabs the first 50k rows and keeps going as long as there are 50k more rows to grab and it works extremely quickly because I'm usually only getting the last 2 days worth of data.

```
top=50000
i=0
days = 2
df = pd.DataFrame()
result = pd.DataFrame()
curs = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
while((i==0) or (len(df)==top)):
  start_time = (dt.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=days)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  sql=f'SELECT * FROM {str.upper(table)} WHERE INSERTED_AT >= \'{start_time}\' OR UPDATED_AT >= \'{start_time}\' LIMIT {top} OFFSET {i}'    
  curs.execute(sql)
  data = curs.fetchall()
  df=pd.DataFrame([i.copy() for i in data])
  result = result.append(df,ignore_index=True)
  #load result to snowflake
  i += top
```

The trouble is I have a very large table that is about 7 million rows long and growing exponentially. I found that if I backload all its data (day=1000) that I will be missing data probably because each iteration what was 0-50k,50k-100k, etc. has now changed since the table loaded more data whilst I was running the while loop.

What is a better way to load data into snowflake that will avoid missing data issues? Do I have to use parallelization to get all these pieces of the table at once? Even if top=3mil I still find I'm missing large amounts of data, likely due to the lag time it takes me to load while the actual table rows are incrementing. Is there a standardized block of code that excels for large tables?

Comment: Won't you always be missing data? The only way to get it all is to stop everyone running DML on the table while you `select *`.

Comment: Yes, I currently avoid this by referencing the table again in the future as I scan over it with my 50k snapshots. So I'm looking for a more fullproof way to cache the data with Python from AWS to SF without having to reference again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip the Python and favor the UNLOAD Snowflake command.

UNLOAD lets you dump the contents of a Redshift table into an S3 bucket:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Migrate-Data-from-Amazon-Redshift-into-Snowflake

```
unload ('select * from emp where date = GET_DATE()')
to 's3://mybucket/mypath/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX'
delimiter '\001'
null '\\N'
escape
[allowoverwrite]
[gzip];
```

You could set up a stored procedure that runs and have a schedule that kicks it off once per day (I use Astronomer/Airflow for this).

From there you can build an external table on top of the bucket:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html